# Get data from SQL Server 2005 database and display in html table using php?

Tags: php, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, html-table

I've searched over the net for solutions, but yet nothing worked. I have a database (SQL Server 2005). What i want to do is make a php file that connects to the database, get data (e.g SELECT LoginID, Password, IP FROM DBName) and display it in html table e.g:

```
<th>LoginID</th><th>Password</th><th>IP</th>
```

I have already installed xampp and sql server driver for php. Here's the phpinfo output:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You really shouldn't ever create anything that displays passwords like this. To be honest, you should always store your passwords salted and hashed.

Comment: That password field is only for example :)

Comment: OK. So what have you tried? This really shouldn't be too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i've tried:

```
<?php
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$serverName = "SERVER/SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"game33");

/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// 
?>
```

Output:

Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 53 [code] => 53 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 53 [code] => 53 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )